# how to reference acts_as_tenant current_tenant from cancan ability.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, acts-as-tenant

I have some overall permissions set against the current_tenant - I can reference these from within a controller i.e.

```
current_tenant.has_some_capability?
```

works fine.

I would like to wrap this up using CanCan, if I put the following in my ability.rb I get undefined local variable or method `current_tenant' for #

```
if current_tenant.some_capability?
    can :manage, Whatever
end
```

Comment: I have resolved this now - it's a scoping issue, current_tenant should always be available just needed to reference it as ActsAsTenant.current_tenant

Answer (score 0):

I believe that CanCan expects `current_user`, try this:

```
current_user = current_tenant
```

Read the first part of the [Getting Started](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan#getting-started)

If you can't access current_tenant from your ability.rb, try setting `@current_tenant` as a before_filter in your application controller:

```
before_filter do
  @current_tenant = current_tenant
end
```